# Scrapy response uniform blank rows making it impossible to format response output

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to remove the [ ] brackets scrapy adds to all it's output, to do this you simply add [0] at the end of an xpath statement as follows:

```
'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

this solves the [ ] problem in some cases but in other cases scrapy returns every second row of output as blank and as such the moment it gets to the second row when using [0] i'm given the error:

```
Index error: list index out of range
```

How can I prevent scrapy from creating blank rows ? It seems like this is a common problem, but everyone faces this problem when exporting to CSV while for me it's with the scrapy response before exporting as CSV.

Items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class QuestionItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    url = Field()

class PopularityItem(Item):
    votes = Field()
    answers = Field()
    views = Field()


class ModifiedItem(Item):
    lastModified = Field()
    modName = Field()
```

The spider that doesn't output every second row as blank and thus works with [0]:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import QuestionItem

class QuestionSpider(Spider):
    name = "questions"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="summary"]/h3')

        for question in questions:
            item = QuestionItem()
            item['title'] = question.xpath(
                'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = question.xpath(
                'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

The spider that gives every second row of output as blank:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import PopularityItem


class PopularitySpider(Spider):
    name = "popularity"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        popularity = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "question-summary narrow")]/div')

        for poppart in popularity:

            item = PopularityItem()
            item['votes'] = poppart.xpath(
                'div[contains(@class, "votes")]//span/text()').extract()#[0]
            item['answers'] = poppart.xpath(
                'div[contains(@class, "answered")]//span/text()').extract()#[0]
            item['views'] = poppart.xpath(
                'div[contains(@class, "views")]//span/text()').extract()#[0]
            yield item
```

Pipelines.py

```
import pymongo
import logging

class StackPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item



from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log

class MongoDBPipeline(object):


    def __init__(self):

        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        self.db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        collection = self.db[type(item).__name__.lower()]
        logging.info(collection.insert(dict(item)))
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle an error like this is to catch it and deal with it then (in this case, by just moving on past the blank lines).

```
class PopularitySpider(Spider):
    name = "popularity"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        popularity = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "question-summary narrow")]/div')
        for poppart in popularity:
            try:
                item = PopularityItem()
                item['votes'] = poppart.xpath('div[contains(@class, "votes")]//span/text()').extract()[0]
                item['answers'] = poppart.xpath('div[contains(@class, "answered")]//span/text()').extract()[0]
                item['views'] = poppart.xpath('div[contains(@class, "views")]//span/text()').extract()[0]
            except IndexError:
                continue
            yield item
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly and is very simple thanks, however when doing this it displays as scrapy output and stores to mongoDB as it should now, but the moment I export as CSV from mongoDB the [ ] brackets and empty rows are back again, any ideas on why this is happening ?

Comment: I have also tried scrapy loaders with "strip" and "join" which has had the same effect, it works as scrapy output and when stored into mongoDB but the moment I export to CSV the problems are back, I had originally thought this was a problem with scrapy but it seems like it's a problem with mongoDB export ?